# Download of .xls not working in firefox

Tags: jsp

I have a website where I upload an excel file named abc.xls for the clients to download.

However when I tried to do a d/l the .xls file on firefox, it won't download, and will just go to the domain.com/abc.xls and there are some alien words as shown on the screenshot.

I tried to d/l the same file using IE, I am able to do it successfully.

Anyone know what could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set the ContentType to 'application/vnd.ms-excel'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a content disposition header

```
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excelTest.xls")
```